# Problem with flash and displayed div

Tags: html, css, flash

Flash banner block up authorization div.
Currently it looks like:

[http://img220.imageshack.us/i/zaslon.jpg/ http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/2623/zaslon.jpg](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/2623/zaslon.jpg)

I want it to be:
[http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/919/screen3e.jpg http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/919/screen3e.jpg](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/919/screen3e.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A detailed solution can be found [here](http://renaun.com/blog/2005/12/08/6/).

And if you use jQuery you can also use [bgIframe](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe) plugin to avoid that in IE6.

Hope this helps,
Sinan.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you the exact answer but it will involve  the z-index and positioning something relatively and making sure you flash has the wmode set to transparent or opaque